# Can an OSX app store app install a browser extension

Tags: macos, installation, browser-extension

I'm working for a client that is getting an OSX app ready for release. They have a stand-alone app that installs browser extensions for the major browsers.

Their new version will be an app store app.

Is it possible to drive the process of installing a browser extension from an OSX app store app? From what I've seen, you have to lead the user to download the extension and then open it from the finder or from the browser's list of downloaded files.

This makes for a rather disjointed, error-prone installation process. The user can fail to download the file, can fail to open the file, or can fail to return to the app to complete the installation process. All of those things are bad, especially since this app is going to be free, with optional paid upgrades. If the user doesn't complete the installation process, my client loses them as a potential upgrade (paid) client.

Comment: So the user downloads the app from the App Store and that app should also install an extension to the browser?  All browsers or specific browsers in particular?

Comment: this link may help for chrome browser :
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

Answer (score 1):

[As of v25 Google Chrome implemented security features which would prevent any extensions installed offline by a 3rd party application from being activated without first being approved by the user via a dialog prompt in the browser.](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html)

[Mozilla had implemented similar security measures over a year prior with Firefox 8](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Silent-installs-of-add-ons-still-possible-in-Firefox-1787297.html)

It's likely been patched by now, but it was reported that you could bypass Firefox security measures and accomplish a silent extension installation by copying the extension directly into the Firefox extension directory and add a record of it to the browsers Sqlite3 database.  The database record involves adding a boolean true value to a property which specifies if the add-on has been approved or not.

[Later versions of Firefox switched to using JSON rather than the Sqlite database and a similar process was still possible.](http://research.zscaler.com/2012/09/how-to-install-silently-malicious.html)

---

If I understand your question correctly.. This is *potentially feasible* regardless of vendor security but impossible for any public production level application due to such security because it will never be stable.

Vendors have a high priority in locking processes like this done to prevent potentially malicious 3rd party code.  Interested in the subject I came across a few possibilities.  I can't guarantee whether or not any of these will work but perhaps it will lead you in the right direction..

---

I would try to do this will Applescript to automate the user actions or potentially guide the user through the process.

You can open the extension with

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"path/to/myextension.safariextz" withApplication:@"Safari"];
```

but that only gets you started.

An alternative possibility was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4393062/1922144

And then there was a discussion here that seems worth noting.. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3067552?tstart=0

```
safari.msi /i /qn BypassDefaultBrowserCheck=true
```

Comment: There are 2 parts to the problem: Installing the plug-ins in the browser, and then getting the browser to accept them. My question focuses on the first part, which is installing plug-in from an app store app.