# Install Safari webdriver on Mac using command line without any user prompting

Tags: macos, safari, webdriver, command, silent-installer

I am setting up Selenium testing for Safari 8 on Mac 10. I need to install our Safari driver beforehand, and it needs to happen silently and without any user prompting.

And also I manually install the safari driver, I saw below files would be changed:

> after install, 3 files in ~/Library/preference has been changed.
>   after install, 7 files in ~/Library/Safari file has been changed 
>   after install, login.keychain in ~/Library/Keychains file has been changed

From previous posts, I've tried these:

1. [Silent install for Safari extension on Mac without any user prompting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981307/silent-install-for-safari-extension-on-mac-without-any-user-prompting).
   I found this works in that it loads the browser with the extension:

   ```
   open -a Safari SafariDriver.safariextz<br>
   ```

   But it leaves the browser opened with a prompt to the user: "Are you sure you want to install the extension?"

   Then I follow the first answer trying to do these: 
   "install the extension into `~/Library/Safari/Extensions` and update `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist`". Here I copy the `SafariDriver.safariextz` to this path: `~/Library/Safari/Extensions`. Then I could not find the `Extensions.plist` in this path `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/`. And I also could not find safari driver related change item in these files `~/Library/preference/com.apple.Safari.plist` or `com.apple.Safari.Extensions.plist`
2. [I am unable to install my extension to safari from commandline (OS X 10.5.8 Safari 5+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391761/i-am-unable-to-install-my-extension-to-safari-from-commandline-os-x-10-5-8-safa?lq=1). I use this command from article to try, still with the user prompt:

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/safari /tmp/my-product/my-extension.safariextz<br><br>
   ```

   Could someone answer my questions here with more detail information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this through applescript. 
1. applescript could handle prompt
tell application "Finder"
    set f to POSIX file "/usr/bin/SafariDriver.safariextz"
    if exists f then
        ignoring application responses
            tell application "Safari" to open f
        end ignoring
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Safari"
                set frontmost to true
                repeat until (exists window 1) and subrole of window 1 is "AXDialog" -- 
                    delay 1
                end repeat
                click button 1 of front window -- install
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end tell
2, I have tried to copy related file like manually install files would be modified which are mentioned in my question. I could see the driver shows in Safar->preferency->Extesions. But I didn't not test whether or not it has been installed correctly. I found the Extensions.plist would be in different folder if the OS is different. 
For I have tried two:
 
    1).when in Mac 10.9, it would be modify below file:
~/Library/Preferency: 
    com.apple.safari.plist
    com.apple.finder.plist
~/Library/Safari:
    Extensions/WebDriver.safariextz
    Extensions/Extensions.plist
~/Library/KeyChain:
    log.keychain
    2).when in Mac 10.10, it would be modify below file:
~/Library/Preferency: 
    com.apple.safari.plist
    com.apple.finder.plist
    com.apple.safari.Extension.plist
~/Library/Safari:
    Extensions/WebDriver.safariextz
~/Library/KeyChain:
    log.keychain